# Issue with & for latex and eulerr

Tags: pdftex, symbols, packages, incompatibility, rmarkdown

I'm having some issues with rmarkdown, where I can't generate a pdf because I use "&" when I build a eulerr diagram.

The error is : `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.`

I do use '&' to align some of my code, but this chunk is not within the alignment.

````
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\begin{align*}
equation&equation
\end{align*}
item b
```{r}
euler(c("a"=10,"b"=10,"a&b"=4)) <- recognizing "&" as 
```
\end{enumerate}
````

I've tried using "\&" but eulerr is not recognizing the escape character.
thanks all

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If you think that triple backquotes work like in Markdown, as used on this site, then I'm afraid you're wrong. You perhaps want the `verbatim` environment.

Comment: the triple ticks are for code chunks in Rmarkdown